# How to convert ja.sql.timestamp to given format using java

Tags: java, postgresql

Storing the time in UTC timezone in DB.After fetching from the DB Need to convert the time in the given format "20201218064312+0800"

here + should take care of the summer time as well.

Comment: What is wrong using DateTimeFormat class?

Comment: the problem is how to take care of summer time here

Comment: Java together with OS takes care of this.

Comment: Try it out. SO is not a programming service. If you still do not get it, paste here your attempts, your inputs, your expectations and outcomes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should retrieve the date-time into a `LocalDate` object as shown below:

```
LocalDate ldt = rs.getObject(1, LocalDate.class));
```

Then convert `ldt` into an `OffsetDateTime odt` using `LocalDateTime#atOffset`. Finally, convert `odt` into `ZonedDateTime` with the same instant by using `odt.atZoneSameInstant` to which you will have to pass the `ZoneId` as the argument. `ZonedDateTime` has been designed to take care of variation in time due to summer/winter change automatically.

Finally, use the appropriate `DateTimeFormatter` to print the date-time in the desired format.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // I have created this instance of LocalDateTime for the purpose of demo. This
        // should come from your ResultSet
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-12-15 17:38:40.962",
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
        OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(odt);

        // Convert the odt to Zone
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/Vatican");
        ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant(zoneId);
        System.out.println(zdt);

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmssXX");
        System.out.println(zdt.format(dtf));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-15T17:38:40.962Z
2020-12-15T18:38:40.962+01:00[Europe/Vatican]
20201215183840+0100
```

**A quick demo of how `ZonedDateTime` automatically adjusts the timezone offset:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime ldtSummer = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 06, 02, 6, 0, 0);
        LocalDateTime ldtWinter = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 12, 02, 6, 0, 0);
        ZoneId nyZone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
        ZonedDateTime nyZdtSummer = ldtSummer.atZone(nyZone);
        ZonedDateTime nyZdtWinter = ldtWinter.atZone(nyZone);
        System.out.println(nyZdtSummer);
        System.out.println(nyZdtWinter);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2017-06-02T06:00-04:00[America/New_York]
2017-12-02T06:00-05:00[America/New_York]
```

Comment: how this will take care of summer time

Comment: @Rekha - `ZonedDateTime` automatically adjusts the timezone offset. I have added a demo to illustrate it. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.

Comment: Thank you for the demo.The db has "2020-12-15 17:38:40.962".I am trying display in Europe/Vatican zone.I am getting wrong value 20201215130840+01:00.Could you please correct me on this

Comment: public String getTimeWithSpecifiedTimeZoneWithDayLightSavings(Timestamp dbTimeStamp) {
  OffsetDateTime objOffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(dbTimeStamp.getTime()),
    ZoneId.of("UTC"));
  ZonedDateTime zdt = objOffsetDateTime.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Vatican"));
  DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmssXXX");
  return zdt.format(dtf);
 }

Comment: @Rekha - I've updated the answer based on this information. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt. You should add all these details in the question. Next time when you post a question, try to put all relevant information so that these many communications can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

`java.sql.Timestamp` represents solarflares time: A moment in time independent of timezone or political changes to timezones. Rendering it as `20201218064312+0800` is therefore impossible; not enough info is enclosed in that Timestamp object to do it.

Convert to appointments-time first, and it is easy from there.

- **solarflares time** is a moment in time independent of politics or locations. It happened/will happen at exactly X seconds from now. Timezones or political decrees that zones change, daylight savings, etc, have zero effect. Stated in milliseconds; days, months, years, etc make no sense here. Represented by `Instant`.
- **appointments time** is how humans tend to do time, and as specific as possible. Stated in terms of years, months, days, and timezone. Note that `+0800` is not a timezone, not a useful one anyway, and not a zone anybody ever makes appointments in. `Europe/Amsterdam`, that's a timezone. This is used for appointments: If I call up my barber and make an appointment for next tuesday at `08:00`, you should store that as an appointments-time. This is important: If the political entity that decides time stuff for the location my barber is at decides that we aren't going to do daylight savings this year after all on short notice, that means my appointment is now effectively an hour earlier or later in absolute (solarflares) time. That's the difference between solarflares and appointments time. Represented by `ZonedDateTime`.
- **alarm clock time** is how you tend to configure your alarm clock. With appointment time, if I fly from europe to the US, the absolute # of seconds until my barber appointment does not change. However, if I set an alarm because I want to wake up at 8 in the morning, that does change; '8 in the morning' is now different. Represented by `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, and `LocalDateTime`.
- the `j.u.Date` and `j.u.Calendar` APIs are stupid, do not use them: They did not realize that time works in 3 different ways, and conflate all 3. It means that the methods make no sense (and in the case of the Date API, are all deprecated because they make no sense) and give wrong answers. Hence, do not use them. Use the `java.time` API, the only one that makes sense. If you can't, because e.g. the JDBC spec forces crappy APIs on you, convert to java.time ASAP, and into the right one of the 3 representations first, THEN do your conversions.

The crucial thing to get is that j.s.Timestamp is a solarflares time (and so is `j.u.Date` - yes, it is epically misnamed). Effectively then you're asking to turn a solarflares time to `20201218064312+0800`, and that's weird, because solarflares time is not very compatible with the notions of 'months', 'days', 'years', and 'timezones'. appointments time is much better at that, thus, convert to that first, and then it is easy. Thus, the formula is:

1. Convert Timestamp to the most appropriate java.time type, which is `Instant` (because technically that is what a Timestamp is implemented as: millis-since-epoch+nanos-in-that-milli)
2. Convert your Instant to a ZonedDateTime, because the rendering you desire includes concepts that an Instant does not understand: Human concepts, like 'month'.
3. Convert your ZDT to a ZDT in the location you want. Instants do not include any notion of location/zone, hence why you need to explicitly specify you want the strange, never used by humans `+0800` zone for some bizarre reason.
4. Format your properly located ZDT using a DateTimeFormatter.

NB1:
Are you quite sure you want +0800? I bet you want `Asia/Singapore` or some such, not `+0800`, and then render that like this, though, really, you shouldn't do that, it gets confusing when countries decide to switch zones, which they do all the time. Stating things like `+0800` is a great way to miss barber appointments.

NB2: Steps 2 and 3 above can be done in a single step, but it is good to realize you're combining things.

Comment: I have just given example.If it is  asia/kolkata then it should be +0530..Basically timezone will be configurable.Based on that we need to convert.